# Schengen travel with minor Indian child born in Netherlands

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, netherlands, minors

We plan a travel to Germany and Austria with our 5 month old baby who is holding a indian passport issued by Indian embassy in Netherlands  but does not have Dutch resident permit id. Is it ok to travel with the birth certificate issued by the Netherlands government and the passport of my child or a valid visa would be required for my child. We as parents do have a valid passport and Dutch resident permit id.

Thanks in advance

---

Thanks for you inputs. I am aware of the Dutch law that if a child is born in Netherlands and parents are Indian by origin then the child will be an Indian by registration.
My question was that will the minor child be able to travel based on resident permit of the parents.

Comment: Not familiar with the dutch nationality law, is the child a dutch citizen because he/she was born there? In that case you should get a passport. If not, a visa is very probably a requirement.

Comment: It seems the chances the child would have dutch citizenship at birth are pretty slim. Information about residence permits for children born in the Netherlands: https://ind.nl/en/family/Pages/Child-born-in-the-Netherlands.aspx

Comment: @jcaron even if the child were a Dutch citizen, the parents might want to avoid the loss of Indian citizenship that would be triggered by applying for a Dutch passport.  This can pose a problem for children of Indian parents born abroad, because the country of birth generally won't issue a visa or residence permit because the child is a citizen.  This effectively forces such children to expatriate themselves (or forces parents to expatriate their children).

Answer (score 3):

The child will require his or her own residence permit.  See [Child born in the Netherlands](https://ind.nl/en/family/Pages/Child-born-in-the-Netherlands.aspx) on the website of the Dutch IND for information about how to apply.

However, if you travel to Germany or Austria without a residence permit, you are unlikely to receive much worse than a warning if this comes to the attention of government authorities.  In the worst case, you will probably be liable to pay a fine.

If you will be flying, you should check with the airlines to see whether they will require proof of immigration status for your child.

Comment: Indeed, if the OP is an Indian resident in NL (as it sounds), Germany and Austria is intra-Schengen travel and it is most likely there will be no visas check of any type.